# regular expression for string " a123ab-lift(admin-hat)"

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to know the regex which confirms to

**a123ab-lift(admin-hat)**

My string can contain alphabets, numbers and characters `" ( " , " ) " , " - "`

Comment: What is the regex if I want to confirm whether my input string can have anything except carriage return and line feeds I e. \r ,\n

Answer (score 1):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\(\)\-]*
```

matches strings containing characters a to z, A to Z, 0 to 9, `(`, `)`and `-`. Those last three characters are escaped by a preceding backslash because they have a special meaning when used in a regex (although, in this case, escaping is not necessary. See hwnd's comment).

Comment: They don't necessarily need to be escaped inside of the character class.

Comment: Agreed. I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following will work.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9()-]*
```

Example:

```
String s  = "a123ab-lift(admin-hat)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9()-]*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
System.out.println(m.matches()); // True
```

Comment: My requirement is that the input string should not contain any carriage return and line feeds (I.e \r, \n)anywhere

Comment: You need to use `MULTILINE` and add `^` and `$` anchors

Answer (score 0):

This matches what you have in your title.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]*(-|\.)+\w\*\(admin-hat\)
```

Comment: What is the regex if I want to conform that my string does not have any carriage returns and line feeds .

Comment: do you need to check it at the end? something like this...[^\s]$

Comment: Not specifically at the end..it can be anywhere within a string. I just need to ensure that the string does not contains any carriage return and line feeds

Comment: this checks if atleast one of those exists in the string "\\s+" I believe for java